# Check if multiple bits are set or cleared

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I wish to check if multiple bits in a 32-bit register are set or cleared for the purpose of manipulating hardware. I adopt the following approach to check if the desired bits (bit 8 and bit 1) of an `uint32_t`-variable called `statusRegister` are set:

```
if ((statusRegister & 0x00000102) == 0x00000102) {}
```

And the following to check if the wanted bits are cleared:

```
if ((statusRegister | ~0x00000102) == ~0x00000102) {}
```

Is this correct? Is there a more concise way of doing it?

Comment: Why do you need alternatives? Especially the first (checking bits set) is very clear and easy to understand. The second is a little harder, but you could simply do `(statusRegister & 0x00000102) == 0` instead.

Comment: Now that the question is edited @Someprogrammerdude, I think you could convert your comment into an answer:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To check whether multiple bits are cleared, you'd typically use this somewhat more concise idiom:

```
if ((statusRegister & 0x00000102) == 0) {}
// or
if (!(statusRegister & 0x00000102)) {}
```

You could also check whether multiple bits are set with:

```
if ((statusRegister | ~0x00000102) == ~0) {}
// or
if (!(~statusRegister & 0x00000102)) {}
```

But the version in your question is much more common. ANDing with a bitmask is the simplest mental model and easiest to understand for your fellow programmers.